# Undefined local variable or method `__File__' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, macos, irb, nameerror

I am new to Ruby and am completing an online course on Lynda.

In my text editor I have:

```
APP_ROOT = File.dirname(__File__)

$:.unshift ( File.join(APP_ROOT, 'lib))
require 'guide
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
init.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `__File__' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: 'File' should be a file name,just like: File.dirname("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb")   #=> "/home/gumby/work"

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

This is a common ruby idiom to get the directory of the executing file.

Comment: Oops! I didn't realize using the underscores had changed File.dirname(__FILE__) to have FILE in bold. I did actually put what you posted and am getting the error I posted above, but with FILE as you wrote it

Comment: Make the that `__FILE__` is in all capitals.

Comment: Ah figured it out! Thank you for you help. I had copied the file into the folder. And a remaining copy was still on my desktop.